# Big Oh in n^2 and n lg n

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I know that **n<sup>2</sup>** is polynomial. Logarithmic algorithms are fast. But I am confused with different inputs of data. What are the cases for small inputs and large inputs?

For example, say you have two sorting algorithms:

B is O(n<sup>2</sup>)
      and
 Q is O(n lg n).

Is Q always faster than B? Please provide your thoughts for both the cases.

Answer (score 2):

Big O notation hides a multiplicative constant, so it is possible that for some small value of n that the O(n^2) algorithm may be faster.

Big O just guarantees that after some input size of x, the algorithm with the lower growth rate WILL run in less time (I assume we are doing O of time, but it could also refer to space or other factors).

Comment: And even if there were no multiplicative constant, Big O just guarantees that at some constant value for n, for all sizes of n greater than that constant, one of the algorithms will always be faster.

Comment: True, your constant could be 1. If you assume the constant is 0, you will lose points on your exam. Similarly, O(infinity) is considered poor form.

Comment: Hah, fair enough.  My "no multiplicative constant" meant the identity constant, i.e. 1 not 0.

Comment: It does NOT guarantee that for large input (larger then any constant value) B will be faster then A. This is because big O gives only *upper bound*. Note that `f(n)=n` is also in `O(n^2)` - thus it could be that A is a linear scan, and B is merge sort. A will always be faster then B. It seems you refered to big Theta rather then big O in your answer.

Comment: Big O describes the upper bound of the growth, yes, but it is completely useless if you don't provide a tightly bounding function. I stated earlier that one ~could~ call any function O(infinity), but this is not very helpful. I agree that Big Theta would be a better technical representation of the growth of the function, but a properly formed (tightly bound) Big O should be just as good in practice.

Answer (score 1):

n^2 is polynomial - 2^n is exponential

Big-oh deals with asymptotic complexity, meaning when "n" is large; so the answer to your question is "false."  If the O(n^2) algorithm has an exact run-time of n^2, and the O(n lg n) algorithm has an exact run-time of 10 * n lg n, then for small n the n^2 algorithm will be faster (e.g., n = 5; 5 ^ 2 = 25, 10 * 5 * lg(5) is about 100).  However, for large n the "10*" factor is irrelevant.

Sometimes an algorithm will combine two or more algorithms to capitalize on this; for example, insertion-sort is O(n^2) but has a small constant factor while mergesort is O(n lg n) with a larger constant factor, so when mergesort has split its sub-arrays into small enough chunks it will then use an insertion-sort on them.